# How can I accept IPIP connection in CentOS 7?

Tags: networking, centos, route, mikrotik, tunnel

Guys I have a server with Mikrotik Router OS installed on it and there are some PPTP users using that server as a VPN server . What I want to do is to create an IPIP tunnel between this Mikrotik Server and a CentOS 7 server !

What I'm trying to accomplish is that I want the PPTP users on server 1 (Mikrotik) to have the IP address of server 2 (CentOS 7) . I basically want all the traffic of the first server to be sent over to the CentOS 7 server and then from there to the internet .

Now I have everything set up on the Miktrotik side of things ! I have created an IPIP tunnel interface and assigned IP addresses to it and also created a static route for it .

However I don't enough knowledge to configure the CentOS part . I have read a tutorial and created an ipip interface on CentOS like following :

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ipip

DEVICE=ipip
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=no
TYPE=IPIP
PEER_OUTER_IPADDR=195.52.213.219
PEER_INNER_IPADDR=10.20.40.2
MY_INNER_IPADDR=10.20.40.1
```

also added the following :

```
ifup ipip
ifconfig ipip
```

to the rc.local file so that the interface comes up when the system boots .

After that I create a route like following :

```
ip route add 10.20.40.2 dev ipip proto kernel scope link src 10.20.40.1
```

but these don't seem to be working . The CentOS server is not accepting anything from the Mikrotik server . Am I doing it correctly? I'm pretty sure that the configuration on the Mikrotik Side is correct however , I don't know how to Configure CentOS to accept traffic from the Mikrotik Router and send it to the internet . Any kind of help is appreciated .

Comment: That is a tunnel, so you set up a tunnel interface.

Comment: can you be a little more specific? Isn't this what I have done right now?

Comment: guys any help is appreciated .